# Javascript closure doubts for click event

Tags: javascript, html, closures

My JS code :-

```
 var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    var li= document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML='this is my li  '+ i+ '.';
    li.onclick = (function (){
        return (function (){
            alert(i);
        })
    })();
    ul.appendChild(li);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(ul);
```

Test code -- http://jsfiddle.net/VhfEh/112/

Html View :-

```
this is my li 0.
this is my li 1.
this is my li 2.
this is my li 3.
this is my li 4.
this is my li 5.
this is my li 6.
this is my li 7.
this is my li 8.
this is my li 9.
```

When I am clicking on any of the `li` I am getting 10.. which is the max value of `i` or it is `i++` value..

I tried something but its not working ??

**Doubts :-**

- Function with in a function is not Closure in JavaScript ?
- Example I am using is the JavaScript Closure example ??

Thanks !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're really close; you just forgot to set up and use a parameter with that anonymous function:

```
li.onclick = (function (i) {
    return (function (){
        alert(i);
    })
})(i);
```

The whole point of the immediately-executed function is to give each handler a private copy of the loop variable, so you have to actually pass it in as a parameter like that.

Comment: Example I am using is the JavaScript Closure's example ??

Comment: One of my co-worker told me function with in a function definition is not the Closure in JavaScript ? Can you please make this concept clear for me.. ?

Comment: @Neeraj I'm not sure I understand your question ... yes, that code creates a closure, but the problem was that without introducing that parameter (or something like Lee Meador's answer, which should also work), you were not taking advantage of what the closure can do.

Comment: @Neeraj The closure was there before because of the function.  But unless you have some arguments or variables defined inside a function, nothing gets stored. Oh and ... A function in a function creates a closure inside a closure but, again, it doesn't much matter if you don't store anything in it.

Answer (score 2):

You are right about needing a closure.

You have to keep the `i` somewhere inside the closure that is created by the function body:

```
li.onclick = (function (){
    var localI = i;
    return (function (){
        alert(localI);
    })
})();
```